# Boundary of the following double integrals (solution check)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, multiple-integral

I've still been practicing double integrals since my last question and now I have the last 2 left that I am not sure if I did the boundary right and I'd need someone to correct me if I am wrong.

$\left(1\right)$ $$\int \:\int _D\frac{\:x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dxdy\:$$

where$\:D:\:x=0,\:x=y,\:y=1,\:y=\sqrt[3]{2}$

For this one I chose $0\le x\le 1$ so my integral will look like: $$\int _0^1\left(\int _1^{\sqrt[3]{2}}\:\frac{\:x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dy\right)dx$$

$\left(2\right)$ $$\int \:\int _D\:ylnx\:dxdy\:$$ where$\:D:\:xy=1\:,\:y=\sqrt{x},\:x=2$

For this one I really am not sure how to do it honestly, even if I did the graph I don't understand, I assume $0\le x\le 2$ so my integral will be: $$\int _0^2\left(\int _{\frac{1}{x}}^{\sqrt{x}}\:ylnx\:dy\right)dx\:$$

I don't want to evaluate them, just to see if I can do the boundary properly now.

Comment: I suggest you draw a picture of the boundary. It's much easier to write it down that way @tryingtosolvethispain

Comment: I did but I am so stupid I have trouble even with that, I can't tell for example for the first one if it's $0\le x\le 1$ or it's $0\le x\le \sqrt[3]{2}$, as for the second one again I can't tell if it's $0\le x\le 2$ or it's $\sqrt{2}\le x\le 2$. @Buraian

Comment: They probably meant the domain enclosed by those curves, so do you see some area enclosed after plotting all the curves? @tryingtosolvethispain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first one, you will have to split your integral into two if you are integrating over $dy$ first. I would recommend over $dx$ first.

The integral will be,

$\displaystyle \int_1^{2^{1/3}} \int_0^y f(x,y) \ dx \ dy$

For second one, your bounds of $x$ is incorrect. Lower bound is at the intersection of $y = \sqrt x$ and $xy = 1 \implies x = 1$. The upper bound is $x = 2$

So the integral should be,

$ \displaystyle \int_1^2\int _{\frac{1}{x}}^{\sqrt{x}}\: f(x,y) \ dy \ dx\:$

Comment: I especially had trouble on the $(2)$nd one since I wasn't sure if I should take from $0$ or from the intersection, I was doing it in desmos but I still couldn't figure out for the lower bound, I got it now thanks again! Also it's just out of habit I choose to start with $dy$ each time I evaluate them.

Answer (score 1):

The first integral doesn't seem right, I think you haven't got the correct concept yet. Here is a desmos graph I made:

[image]

> The line $x=1$, I have brought in just to drill in the point which I am going to explain. Please note that this is not a boundary as given in the question.

The region from the curves in question is the blue area + the green area. For the green area, it just a rectangle so you can do the way you did it. You need to account the blue area as well, which has a bit more trickier integral expression. Here is my [desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/okxnk8o5ah)

Comment: I was redoing the pictures as well in desmos, yes now I understood and it's easier, thanks!

Comment: The second one could you explain the difficulty you face a bit more?  I couldn't really pick up on why you found it difficult @tryingtosolvethispain

Comment: Might have been because I haven't slept for a while and I am a bit tired been practicing these for quite a few hours but if we put the 2nd one on desmos I thought I had to go from $0$ to $x=2$ rather than going from the intersection of $xy=1$ and $y=\sqrt{x}$, I don't know if I expressed myself properly but yea, it was a stupid mistake I have done, also I did a missclick right now sorry if you got a notification my fault